# Github Commit Hash in Javascript or React.js

Tags: javascript, html, git, github, git-commit

I am trying to create a Javascript component that replaces the static HTML element **Demo v0.1** into the shortened GitHub Commit Hash, e.g. 6da724d

```
<div className ="demo-version">
  Demo v0.1
</div>
```

How to write the javascript code with `git rev-parse HEAD` to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way IMO would be to separate coding (in git) and deploy phases. During deploying you can do whatever you want with your code (replace strings, e.g) and the modified code doesn't clutter your repository.

If you insist on having the hash in source files in the worktree you could use clean/smudge git filters to do keyword substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash script to launch your application and pass an environment variable that will contain the git commit hash.
For example, an easy script for React could be

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
HEAD_GIT_COMMIT="$(git rev-parse HEAD)" yarn start
```

Then since React uses node as the development server, you can access the env var via `process.env.HEAD_GIT_COMMIT`, although you might have some config to write depending on the bundler you are using, or CRA.

Depending on how you are deploying your application on different servers, you might need to adjust the script to make it work with different environments, but you get the idea.